# Remove variable wrapped in function from model formula in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a model with transformed variables, e.g.:

```
 data = data.frame(y = runif(100,0,10), x1 = runif(100,0,10), x2 =   runif(100, 0, 10))
 mod = lm(y ~ scale(x1) + scale(x2), data)
```

I would like to remove one entire variable from the formula, like so:

```
mod = lm(y ~ scale(x1), # x2 is gone! 
 data)
```

But I would like to do this using a user-supplied character string of the variable to be removed (in other words, I'm wrapping this in a function and its not feasible to edit the formula by hand, as I have here).

If the variable was untransformed, this would be simple using `gsub`:

```
remove.var = "x2"
update(mod, formula. = as.formula(gsub(remove.var, "", format(formula(mod)))))
```

but as such, it returns the wholly predictable error:

```
 > Error in as.matrix(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

because `scale()` is still in the formula!

Is there a way to do this with `regexpr`, or some way that I am not seeing that is totally obvious? I would like it to be scalable to other types of transformations, e.g.: `log`, `log10`,etc.

As another layer of complexity, suppose that the variable to be removed also appeared in an interaction:

```
 mod = lm(y ~ scale(x1) * scale(x2), data)
```

In this case, one would have to remove the interaction `*` as well (errant `+`s, I have found, are ok).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It kind of seems like you're going this backwards. How are you building the formula in the first place? Trying to remove parts (or functions of parts or interactions with parts) can be quite complicated after the fact. Seems like you should just build the formula based on the user input directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A terms-object is a formula with additional attributes:

```
update(mod, formula=drop.terms(mod$terms, 2, keep.response=TRUE)  )

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ scale(x1), data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    scale(x1)  
     5.0121       0.1236
```

If you need to calculate that position from a string argument, then you can grep the term.labels attribute:

```
> grep( "x2", attr( mod$terms, "term.labels") )
[1] 2
```

Notice that this also succeeds with the interaction formula:

```
update(mod, formula=drop.terms(mod$terms, grep( "x2", attr( mod$terms, "term.labels") ), keep.response=TRUE) )
#----------

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ scale(x1), data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    scale(x1)  
     5.0121       0.1236
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's another way to do this with the `caret` package, but I think this does what you want:

```
vars<- c("tom", "dick", "harry")
remove<- "tom"
vars<- setdiff(vars, remove)

formula <- as.formula( paste( "y ~", paste("scale(", vars, ")", collapse = "+")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@IRTFM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26898357), I made this function:

```
#' Drop var_name from the_formula.
#'
#' Also drops interaction terms involving var_name.
#'
#' See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151756
#' @param the_formula  Formula object
#' @param var_name  Name of var to drop.
drop_formula_term <- function(the_formula, var_name) {
  var_position <- grep(
    var_name, attr(terms(the_formula), "term.labels"))
  update(
    the_formula,
    drop.terms(terms(the_formula), var_position,
               keep.response=TRUE))
}
```

Example:

```
> a_formula <- as.formula('x ~ a + b + c + a:b + b:c')
> drop_formula_term(a_formula, 'b')
x ~ a + c
> drop_formula_term(a_formula, 'a')
x ~ b + c + b:c
> drop_formula_term(a_formula, 'z')
 Error in reformulate(attr(termobj, "term.labels")[-dropx], response = if (keep.response) termobj[[2L]],  : 
  'termlabels' must be a character vector of length at least one
```